# Searching an array by a variable contained in an instance of an object rather than the array number?

Tags: java

I am creating an array of customer accounts for a company called "customers". I have a method called `getGasAccount` which will count the number of accounts in the array.

I declared variables in the program class as:

```
final int MAXACCOUNTS = 10;
int intNUmber, intSelectAccount;
```

I set up the accounts using:

```
if (GasAccount.getGasAccount() < MAXACCOUNTS) {
   intSelectAccount = GasAccount.getBankAccount()++;
   customers[intSelectAccount] = new GasAccount();
}
```

I want to be able to search for a customer by their account number which is manually input when the constructor is called. I don't want to search by the `intSelectAcocunt`/array reference.

If I have a method called `displayAccountDetails`, is there another way of finding the account rather than using:

```
customers[intSelectAccount].displayAccountDetails();
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? You forgot to tell us.

Comment: You should show us the code for your customer class.  The customer class should have a method that returns its account number.  You can find a customer by account id by iterating over your list/array of customer objects and comparing each one's account ID to the one in question.

Comment: Hi @Jahroy, thanks for your reply. Customer class does include a return method for the customerID. That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Since your question is: "how can I find an Account object without using array indexes", I'll ask a counter-question: why use an array at all?  Why not a `Map<String, Account>`?

Answer (score 1):

Implement `equals` method in `GasAccount` like this

```
public boolean equals(Object objToCompare){
    if (objToCompare != null){
        return objToCompare instanceof GasAccount && ((GasAccount)objToCompare).getAccountNumber() == getAccountNumber();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now to find the location of `GasAccount` object in the array and to display the account details:

```
java.util.List<GasAccount> gasAccountsList = (java.util.List<GasAccount>)java.util.Arrays.asList(customers);
int objectIndex = gasAccountsList.indexOf([Gas Account Object]);
if (objectIndex != -1){
    gasAccountsList.get(objectIndex).displayAccountDetails();
}
```

Another simple approach suggested by **jahroy** to search by account number is :

```
public void getAccountDetails(int accountNumber){
    java.util.List<GasAccount> gasAccountsList = (java.util.List<GasAccount>)java.util.Arrays.asList(customers);
    for(GasAccount gasAccountObj : gasAccountsList){
        if(gasAccountObj.getAccountNumber() == accountNumber){
            gasAccountObj.displayAccountDetails();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
public void getAccountDetails(int accountNumber){
    for(GasAccount gasAccountObj : customers){
        if(gasAccountObj.getAccountNumber() == accountNumber){
            gasAccountObj.displayAccountDetails();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should encourage the use of a non-typed list and unnecessary casting... Also, you need to pass an argument to Arrays.asList().

Comment: @jahroy Thanks for pointing out the `Arrays.asList` point. corrected now.

Comment: I would also clean up the IDE generated equals code, but that's just splitting hairs ;-)   +1

Comment: To use this answer, you have to construct a new customer object and use that to search.  It would be more useful (and very easy to implement) a method that stictly searches for customers by account id.

Comment: Right. Updated my answer. I think this method fits as a solution for the question.

Comment: This is a better appraoch, but why even bother to convert the array to a list?  You can iterate over the orinal array with a simple for each loop (there's no need to convert to list **OR** to use an iterator).

Comment: To keep consistent with the above statements, I continued the `List` conversion. Didn't used iterator.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure that you want is a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). You can do something like this.

```
public class AccountClass{

    //You can fill in the details. I sounds like you know about constructors
    //getters, setters, etc.

    private HashMap<String, String> accountHash = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public HashMap<String, String> getHashMap()
    {
        return this.accountHash;
    }
}
```

when you want to look up an account by account number, you will be able to do something like this.

```
AccountClass acct = new AccountClass();
acct.getHashMap().get("1234");
```

assuming that you have actually put an entry with account number "1234" in your map it will return the value associated with that key.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) is the Wikipedia article if you want to do more reading.

Edit: I have a few more things to add based on some comments.

It might be better if you made the HashMap static like this

```
private static HashMap<String, String> accountHash = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

When you declare the variable static this makes it so that you don't have to instantiate an object to access the HashMap. You can just do something like this.

```
AccountClass.accountHash.get();
```

or
    AccountClass.accountHash.put();

If you want to add things to your HashMap, you need to use the put method. Here is an example.

```
accountHash.put("1234","My test account").
```

Now when you use this,
    accountHash.get("1234");//you will get My test account

you will get the value associated with the "1234" key.

Keep in mind this example is just to give you an idea about how to use it. You can have a map of , , or whatever else you want.

Comment: Using a HashMap is a good idea.  I recommend demonstrating how to populate the map (show how to use put).  Also, in your example code, there's no reason to create a new account instance one line before assinging `acct` to an object that comes from the map.  Your example code creates a new object for no reason then discards it immediately.  Also... if the map is going to be part of `AccountClass` it should probably be static.

Comment: Thanks guys, lots of ideas to play around with. Have never used HashMap before, will get reading.